# using a WCF NettcpBinding within monotouch

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, nettcpbinding

Is it possible to use NetTcpBinding with monotouch?
I done this successfuly using VisualStudio
At the moment, I am trying to use mostly the same code but impossible to compile within MonoTouch. NetTcpBinding is not find in my "using System.ServiceModel;"

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, MonoTouch supports only the BasicHttpBinding by now. [Here's](http://wiki.monotouch.net/index.php?title=HowTo/WebServices/Using_WCF) a sample how to use it.

Here's Geoff Nortons statement:

> MonoTouch supports the same WCF
>   bindings as the Silverlight 3 client
>   profile which is limited to
>   BasicHttpBinding at this time

Good luck,
Waescher